# Writing a direct product of rings over a ring "as one".

Tags: ring-theory

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and suppose that $R/I \oplus R/J$ as ring where I and J are ideals not coprime. Suppose that I wanted to write this as $R[x_1,\ldots ,x_n]/K$ where K is an ideal of the polynomial ring.  Are there any economic way of doing this if I say, knew the generators of I and J? Adding variables is OK, if it makes the process more slick.

I edited the question to make it more ask what I wanted to ask. To ease the process, you can assume R is Noetherian.

Comment: The [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#Statement_for_general_rings) comes to mind

Answer (score 1):

If $I + J = R$, then we have the following: let $K = I \cdot J$ (the [product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_%28ring_theory%29#Ideal_operations) of the two ideals).  Then we have
$$
R/K \cong R/I \oplus R/J
$$
See the [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#Statement_for_general_rings) for the reverse of what you're looking for.

Comment: Right, I am aware of CRT but I was curious if one could speed up the decomposition by adding variables (i.e consider some quotient of R[t] ) or some other method.

Comment: Ah, that I don't know

Comment: Or say when I and J are not coprime, one needs something more than R/K, so one must add variables. I should probably have asked how to do this when I and J are not coprime and when one is allowed to add variables.